# Coefficient marginal to interactions in linear regression

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients, terminology

Consider this model:

$$y = \beta_0 +\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2 + \varepsilon$$

Somebody told me today that the coefficient for the main effect of $x_1$ (i.e., $\beta_1$) will be 'marginal to the interaction'.

Could somebody explain what 'marginal to the interaction' means?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't phrase it that way.  The common meaning of "[marginal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution)" in statistics (and the way I use it) is roughly 'ignoring'.  In other words, the marginal effect of $x_1$ is the effect of a 1-unit change in $x_1$ on $y$ ignoring all other possible variables.  That is *not* what $\beta_1$ represents in that model.  (Note that they may be using the terminology differently than I do, however; that happens.)  To understand the idea of marginal (in the sense of ignoring) in regression better, it may help to read my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830/7290).

Instead, I would say the main effect of $x_1$ (i.e., $\beta_1$) in your model is the effect of a 1-unit change in $x_1$ on $y$ when $x_2=0$.  To get a clearer sense of this, it may help to read my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/84316/7290) (that answer in particular explains in detail what $\beta_1$ means when an interaction is present).