# MANOVA for a Moderator variable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, spss, manova, mancova

I just did a MANOVA to investigate the effect of the my IV on my three DV's.
However, now I want to see if my Moderator Variable has anything to do with it. Can I just put my MV as a covariates? It then becomes a MANCOVA right?

My apologies if this question has been asked, I looked for it but did not find anything that answered my question.

I feel like its so simple, but as i am overthinking it, it confuses me more and more. Please help and save my thesis.

Comment: "Moderator" is just a name for a predictor involved in an _interaction term_ with another predictor. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18848/28500) for example. Thus include both your MV and its interaction with your IV.