# Causal Inference in a Multivariate Equation

Tags: multiple-regression, causality, causal-diagram

I am wondering if both the coefficients can be identified in a causal sense given the context and the resulting multiple regression equation.

Imagine a scenario where we have two investment alternatives denoted $X_1$ and $X_2$, and sales denoted $Y$.

We assume that $X_2$ affects the effect of $X_1$ on $Y$, as well as having a direct effect on $Y$.

Note that $X_2$ affects the effect of $X_1$ on the outcome $Y$ and not the actual value of $X_1$.

I conceptualize this by the following graph:

[image]

Where as green-yellow denotes observed treatment variable, oval white denotes unobserved variable and blue rectangle denotes outcome.

---

I formalize this graph with the following equation:
$\begin{equation}
Y = b_0 + b_1 * X1 + b_2 * X2 + b_3 * x1 * x2 + \epsilon
\end{equation}$

I am facing challenges in understanding whether there should be a direct arrow between $X2$ and $X1$, and arrows directly to sales from the input variables $X1$ and $X2$ instead of having the unobserved effect nodes. Please note that $X2$ does not cause $X1$, but it does influence the effect that $X1$ has on the outcome.

As there are no edges pointing into $X2$ and $X1$, I believe the backdoor criterion is satisfied. However, the equation troubles me since I would propose the same equation given the following scenario: an edge $X1 \rightarrow X2\text{effect}$ and no edge between $X2 \rightarrow X1\text{effect}$.

---

**Question**: is this graphical representation correct given the problem context and secondly, can the estimates be concluded causal by the proposed equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really asking several questions here, which isn't the best use of this site, but we can provide some pointers.

> We assume that 2 affects the effect of 1 on , as well as having a direct effect on .

This pattern is called "moderation", and you can find a huge amount of guidance if you search for that term, particularly if you assume, as you do, that all relationships are linear. This graph can actually be expressed as a straightforward linear regression model:

$y = \alpha + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + b_{12}x_1x_2 + \epsilon$

where $b_{12}$ is the *interaction coefficient* (see ["Moderation" versus "interaction"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18848/42952)).

> I am facing challenges in understanding whether there should be a direct arrow between 2 and 1, and arrows directly to sales from the input variables 1 and 2 instead of having the unobserved effect nodes. Please note that 2 does not cause 1, but it does influence the effect that 1 has on the outcome.

When drawing the DAG for causal inference, arrows just represent dependencies, they don't say anything about what the relationship actually is. Since `X1 effect` just represents the effect of x1 on y, it wouldn't make sense to have an arrow from x1 to y that bypasses this node. However, when actually estimating the model using linear regression, you would want to include the $b_1 x_1$ term in the model, since this captures the linear relationship between x1 and y when x2 $=$ 0.

> However, the equation troubles me since I would propose the same equation given the following scenario: an edge 1→2effect and no edge between 2→1effect.

Yes, lots of people get confused by this, but it's fine. See https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/whats-in-a-name-moderation-and-interaction-independent-and-predictor-variables/

> Question: a) is this graphical representation correct given the problem context and b), can the estimates be concluded causal by the proposed equation?

a) Yes, given what I said above, and b) yes, if you are willing to assume this graph is accurate, but interpreting regression estimates in the presence of interaction terms is tricky.